# Getting req.params in order in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Express, is there a way to get the arguments passed from the matching route **in the order they are defined in the route**?

I want to be able to apply all the params from the route to another function.  The catch is that those parameters are not known up front, so I cannot refer to each parameter by name explicitly.

```
app.get(':first/:second/:third', function (req) {
    output.apply(this, req.mysteryOrderedArrayOfParams); // Does this exist?
});

function output() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Call on `GET: "/foo/bar/baz"`

Desired Output (in this order):

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.route.keys` is an ordered array of parameters whose contents follow `{name:'first'}`.

So, the code:

```
app.get(':first/:second/:third', function (req) {
    var orderedParams = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < req.route.keys; i++) {
        orderedParams.push(req.params[req.route.keys[i].name]);
    }
    output.apply(this, orderedParams);
});

function output() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know via the express route params mechanism, which is a pretty simple subsystem. I think good old `req.path.split('/')` is your friend here.

Comment: What if I have /first/:var1/:var2/blah?  That won't yield me an array of the parameters, just the whacks which is pretty simplistic and not the spirit of the question.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for. The answer to your question, is "no, express doesn't do this for you". If your URLs are so complicated you can't easily parse them, you are probably A) reinventing the venerable query string and B) building complexity you can almost surely avoid with a cleaner redesign.

Comment: I don't really understand that response.  The whole point of routes is that it's parsing my URLs, why would I re-parse them manually?  I already found the answer to my question, so in fact express *does* do this for me via the `keys` array.  Further, you're grabbing static parts of the route here, which defeats the entire purpose of getting only the dynamic bits....

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is the `req.route.params` object.

See more in the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route).

Comment: I cannot do req.route.params[0] on it (it yields `undefined`), it's just an object accessed via req.route.params.first.

However, I did just find `keys` which is in fact an ordered array.

Comment: I haven't look deeply into this, but I believe that express will populate the `req.route.params` object in the order defined in the route. But if you have already fixed your problem, that's what matters

Comment: But it doesn't appear to be an indexible array object, merely a hash with no order or length.  It seems equivalent to `req.params`.

Answer (score 0):

If the you don't want to use param ids but want their order then do this

```
app.get('/:0/:1/:2', function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.params[0]);
    console.log(req.params[1]);
    console.log(req.params[2]);
    res.end();
});

//output

[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
a
b
c
GET /a/b/c 200 5ms
[ 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
c
b
a
GET /c/b/a 200 1ms
```

which will be in the order they match

Comment: Yeah, no clue on that one.  I kicked you back up.  I'm curious, if you call your whack params ":zero", ":one" and ":two" instead of ":0", ":1", and ":2" will this still work?  I tried exactly this and it didn't work.  I wonder if some type coercion or something is going on such that you're not really indexing into an array but instead just getting properties off the object....  Maybe I'm on a different version or something.  Does it work for you to loop over it rather than grabbing the properties individually?

Comment: Sorry, it will only work with integers. Integeral indexes make req.params an array, which would be an object (no order in elements) if it had alphabets in indexes. It is a simple alternative given you sacrifice the use of alpha in your param id names.

Comment: And not a bad one.  Interesting, and thank you for the intel.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading. You are looking to parse the path but your title is what I found when looking for getting the params so I will post an answer.

I used lodash to validate the first parameter (req.params) as a Mongo / ObjectId. In your case though you can index with lodash keys or values...

req.route.keys did not work for me as well as req.params[0]

```html
  if (_.size(req.params) === 1) {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_.values(req.params)[0])) {
      return res.status(500).send('Parameter passed is not a valid Mongo ObjectId');
    }
  }
```